# Azure search relevance

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-search

Need help, I have an azure index called customer and have two fields in it customers & contacts, I have applied boost function for both the fields with boost 100 & 90, the problem is when I search any text it returns customer related relevance first and then contacts relevance.

Eg: If I search for "Johnson"
It will return all the customer details with Johnson first and then contact details even if the contact name matches "Johnson"

List of records displayed.

Record 1: This is customer

1. Johnson & tyson
   Segment: Enterprise   |   Vertical: Healthcare   |   Country: US

Record 2: This is contact however it is associated with customer "Johnson and tyson"

2. Michael Walton 
   Customer:Johnson and tyson  |   Segment: Enterprise   |   Vertical: Pharmaceutical

Record 3: This is contact however it is associated with customer "Johnson and tyson"

3. Henri Vliegen 
   Customer:Johnson and tyson | Segment: Ent  | Vertical: Pharmaceutical

Record 4: This is contact it is associated with customer "WST"

4. Henri Johnson
   Customer:WST |   Segment: Enterprise   |   Vertical: Pharmaceutical

So in this way records are displayed its most probably on scoring however I want the relevance name 
to be displayed first like record 4 is contact and it should have been in place of record 2 since Johnson is the last name

Comment: Tip: Add the azure-search tag to Azure Search related questions to get the attention of the Azure Search engineering team. :)

Answer (score 1):

I believe that it's because you're boosting with the same values, so it's like this:

```
if(Customer.Contains("Johnson") || (Contact.Contais("Johnson"))
{
   //display
}
```

//PS: this statement is just to clarify that Contact and Customer name have the same importance.

Try to boost with different values, and I believe it will work. (100 for Customer and 90 for Details).

**`UPDATE`**

It seems that you are indexing first and last name separately. If you have a field "fullname" and boost through it, probably you'll get the expected result. Another option is create a scoring profile using those fields:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/search-get-started-scoring-profiles/

Comment: Thanks for replying and helping me out... I already tried boosting customer as 100 and contact less than that however it didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

I read the question several times. While the question mentions that you have one index, the records displayed imply that you actually have two search indexes. Is this correct? I've been working on a [training course for Azure Search](https://www.ecofic.com/courses/adding-search-abilities-to-your-apps-with-azure-search), which discusses indexes and scoring in-depth.

At this time, Azure Search does not support cross-index queries. For that reason, if my understanding of your problem is correct, you'd have to run two queries: The first on the Customer index and the second on the Contacts index. Part of the reason that Azure Search is able to execute searches so quickly is because its a flattened out data structure, which allows for fast look-ups and queries. However, you're scenario implies something relational.

Am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: It looks like there are two types of records in a single index, distinguished by which subset of fields are populated. This is a common pattern for fitting related but heterogeneous data in a single index. @harshu288 - Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: Bruce, you are right I have a single index called "customer" and I have fields in it like "id", "customerName", "contactName" and so on. I have applied boost function for customer and contact name not working as per my requirement mentioned in the above question

Comment: I 'm waiting for some help on this